# python get next x elements of numpy array remembering index of the last get

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I had a problem, and I solved it by creating a class:

```py
class ArrayIter:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
        self.index = 0

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        res = self.array[self.index: self.index + n]
        self.index += n
        return res
```

it can be used like this:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(20)
>>> iter = ArrayIter(a)
>>> iter[3]
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> iter[3]
array([3, 4, 5])
>>> iter[6]
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Now something tells me I have reinvented a wheel. Is there something in python's standard library that can do the same? Keep in mind that I'm using numpy arrays and not lists.

Comment: Combining `it = np.nditer(a)` with `np.fromiter(itertools.islice(it, 4), a.dtype)` feels unusual and convoluted. I would use the class.

Comment: you shouldn't redefine the builtin [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)

Comment: The class solution seems optimal: zero copy returning views, nice interface and customizable behavior after exhausting the iterator.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelSzczesny, I will probably continue to use my solution then.

Answer (score 0):

Try generators:

```
a = np.arange(20)
it = iter(a)

def get(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(it)

print(list(get(2)))
print(list(get(3)))
print(list(get(10)))
print(list(get(1)))

# [0, 1]
# [2, 3, 4]
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
# [15]
```

Details: [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855)

Comment: Thank you for your help! There is a problem with this solution, though. The generator is creating a new list each time, while my solution only returns a view into numpy array. If I didn't miss anything. But your solution is still interesting.